# How to set different physical paths for website and FTP site

Tags: windows, iis

How can I set different paths for website and FTP site in such a way that Ftp site points to root directory and website points to subdirectory ([root]\www).

On Windows Server 2016, I'm trying in IIS Manager to set as the physical path for FTP site the root directory of the site (for instance, E:\websites[site_name]), and as the physical path for website the www subdirectory (for instance, E:\websites[site_name]\www).
In IIS Manager, there are separate Advanced Settings for website and FTP site.
When I try to set the physical path for FTP site in the right panel under Menage FTP site > Advanced Settings, the physical path for website is also changed.
When I try to change the physical path for website it produces an analogous result. When I try to set the physical path for website in the right panel under Menage website > Advanced settings then the physical path for FTP site is also changed.
If only one physical path can be set for website and FTP site, it is confusing to set it in two different places.

Comment: Please open up `applicationHost.config` and review how you created them under `sites` tag. For your wishes to come true, you should have two separate sites, not a single one.

Comment: Part of applicationHost.config file you asked about.

Comment: `<site name="mysite" id="41" serverAutoStart="true">
 <application path="/" applicationPool="mysite-AppPool">
  <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="E:\home\mysite" />
  <virtualDirectory path="/cgi-bin" physicalPath="E:\home\mysite\cgi-bin" />
 </application>
 <bindings>
  <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:www.mydomian.net" />
  <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:mydomian.net" />
  <binding protocol="ftp" bindingInformation="*:21:mydomian.net" />
 </bindings>
</site>`

Comment: Are there other solutions, besides two separate sites, to separate the paths for website and FTP site? Could using URL Rewrite mechanism for website and redirecting web requests to www subdirectory solve my issue? Or are there other possible solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause is rather clear that you have a single site with HTTP/FTP bindings and mapped to a single folder. That's why no matter how hard you tried you cannot separate HTTP/FTP.

The only option out there is to use two sites, one for HTTP and the other for FTP. URL rewrite or any other IIS features won't help.

Comment: Site was migrated from an older server. This configuration was due to the desire to preserve the previous solution. 
I'll probably follow your advice. 
Thanks for your help.